# Can something "ring me a bell"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, expressions

It's well known the expression "to ring a bell". "This doesn't ring a bell", "This rings a bell" are commonplace sayings. Is it grammatically correct though to say "this rings me a bell", or "this should ring you a bell"?

Comment: It would not be idiomatic.  Better to say "this rings a bell for me".

Comment: It could happen in my house. Mom (90) said "put me the milk away" this morning.

Comment: @Phil Sweet Some verbs work like that with indirect object pronouns. "Get (for) me a newspaper, would you, please?" So why not "Put (for) me the milk away"? With some it trips off the tongue more easily *Run me a photocopy*, *make me a cup of tea*.

Comment: The number of verbs used benefactively (and perhaps of [non-benefactive] ditransitive verbs) seems to be on the increase (see [Ditransitives in British English Dialects By Johanna Gerwin](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=d-TmBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=%22cry+me+a+river%22+novel+benefactive&source=bl&ots=91TDx8Bn6w&sig=dtKF8BUv6x1sCRCnsqVxgS2mVw8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC0vzOiYvQAhXFD8AKHVPhB2YQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22cry%20me%20a%20river%22%20novel%20benefactive&f=false)). I can remember when 'Cry me a river' would have made me....

Comment: But 'ring' isn't included in any list of two-object verbs I've seen. I'd class this usage as non-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

The verb *ring* means to cause something to make a ringing sound - in other words, the object of the verb is the thing that makes the sound. That's why we say "ring a bell".

If you say "ring me..." then it means you are being rung, i.e. struck to make a sound. The phrase you are looking for is probably "that doesn't ring a bell for me".

"Ring me" can be used in a completely different context with different meanings of the verb, including to call me on the telephone and to put a ring on me like a bird. But not with this meaning.

Comment: But I could see, in dialectical English, a benefactive interpretation— *Buy me a church then ring me a bell* — or perhaps as a personal dative— *I go a-ringing me a bell for New Year's*. It's unclear whether the OP is speaking with a native speaker or not.

Comment: @choster Well, I asked about the grammar of the saying, if that's what you mean. I'm not a native, although I've lived in the UK for a while. Having said that, it's good to know the other interpretation.

Comment: Quite apart from the reams we could write about that, am I wrong to suggest that "this rings…" would be very rare and the well-known expressions very nearly always use "that rings…"?